# Gmail API download attachment selected name

Tags: python, api, gmail

I have a problem with download selected attachment from my gmail account. I wrote app in Python and it works well. But it download every attachment I have on the gmail account. I want to download only one file with strict name or from one sender. Please help me where should I define sender email address which program should find and download only this one attachment. Below my code:

```
def search_emails(query_string: str, label_ids: List = None):
try:
    message_list_response = service.users().messages().list(
        userId="me",
        labelIds=label_ids,
        q=query_string
    ).execute()

    message_items = message_list_response.get('messages')
    next_page_token = message_list_response.get('nextPageToken')

    while next_page_token:
        message_list_response = service.users().messages().list(
            userId="me",
            labelIds=label_ids,
            q=query_string,
            pageToken=next_page_token
        ).execute()

        message_items.extend(message_list_response.get('messages'))
        next_page_token = message_list_response.get('nextPageToken')
    return message_items
except Exception as e:
    raise NoEmailFound("no emails returned")
```

Comment: What query_string are you sending that method?

Comment: it was has: attachment so your question it was answer for my problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your welcome I think.  If you fixed it you may want to answer your own question  may help someone someday.